# OpenGL interleaved VBO - how to get sizeof(Float) in Scala?

Tags: scala, opengl, lwjgl, sizeof, opengl-3

I've been trying to switch from two distinct VBOs to just one with interleaved attributes. I can do it in C++, but in Scala it proves quite difficult.

Here is my implementation:

```
class Mesh(positions: Array[Float], textureCoordinates: Array[Float], indices: Array[Int])
{
    // Create VAO, VBO and a buffer for the indices
    val vao: Int = glGenVertexArrays
    val vbo: Int = glGenBuffers
    val ibo: Int = glGenBuffers

    setup

    private def setup(): Unit =
    {
        val interleavedBuffer: FloatBuffer = prepareFloatBuffer(positions ++ textureCoordinates)
        val indicesBuffer: IntBuffer = prepareIntBuffer(indices)

        // One VAO to bind them all!
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
          glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
          glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)

          // Fill buffers with data
          glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, interleavedBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
          glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

          // Set vertex attribute pointers
          glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 4*5, 0) // 0 = Position = Vector3(x,y,z) -> 3 (coordinates) * 4 (byte-size of float)
          glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 4*5, 4*3) // 1 = Texture Coordinates = Vector2(x,y) -> 2 (coordinates) * 4 (byte-size of float) => stride = 3 (coordinates) + 2 (texture coordinates) = 5 * 4 (byte-size of float); offset = 3 (coordinates) * 4 (byte-size of float)

          glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
          glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
    }

    private def prepareIntBuffer(data: Array[Int]): IntBuffer =
    {
        val buffer: IntBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length)
        buffer.put(data)
        buffer.flip // Make the buffer readable

        buffer
    }

    private def prepareFloatBuffer(data: Array[Float]): FloatBuffer =
    {
        val buffer: FloatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length)
        buffer.put(data)
        buffer.flip // Make the buffer readable

        buffer
    }

    def render(): Unit =
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)
          glEnableVertexAttribArray(0) // Vertices are in zero
          glEnableVertexAttribArray(1) // Texture Coords are in one
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this.indices.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
          glDisableVertexAttribArray(1)
          glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        glBindVertexArray(0)
    }
}
```

The data (positions, textureCoordinates) is the same I used before, with two distinct VBOs for them.

now:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 4*5, 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 4*5, 4*3)
```

How do I calculate these strides and offsets you ask?

Well, position is a Vector3(x, y, z) so 3 floats. Texture coordinates are two floats.

3 + 2 = 5

The size of a float is... well, I thought it was 4 bytes. (according to http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_interleaved it is in Java)

That would give 20, or 4*5

The offset for the texture coordinates would be calculated the same (3 * 4) for each coordinates of the *position*

Now, the outcome doesn't look too good...

[image]

can you guess what it actually should be? (Spoiler: A cube)

So, I figure that either my maths is totally broken or that a Float maybe has a different size in Scala?

In Java I could do Float.size, but Scala doesn't have anything the like it seems.

In C++ I'd define a struct and do:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, textureCoordinates));
```

Comment: This looks bizarre to me: `prepareFloatBuffer(positions ++ textureCoordinates)` Hopefully that's just because I can't read Scala?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: That's array concatenation. And also the source of OP's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not sizeof float, but the data layout in your buffer. The statement

```
val interleavedBuffer: FloatBuffer = prepareFloatBuffer(positions ++ textureCoordinates)
```

Creates a buffer of the layout

```
xyz[0],xyz[1],…,xyz[n],st[0],st[1],…,st[m]
```

However what you configure OpenGL to expect is

```
xyz[0],st[0],xyz[1],st[1],…,xyz[n],st[n]
```

You can either properly interleave the attributes in the buffer, your you tell OpenGL that each attribute's elements are contiguous (0 stride, or the size of exactly one element of that attribute, i.e. 3*4 for xyz and 2*4 for st) and pass offsets to where each subbuffer start.

Comment: There is no standard way to combine two Arrays in Scala that way, is there? I would have to manually build a method for that?

Comment: @Teolha: Yes there is. It's called "zipping" and that's wha the `zip` function is for.

Comment: Doesn't zip create tupled collections? Like Array[(a,b)]?

Comment: @Teolha: Yes, but you can then flatten that using `flatMap`: http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/ – I don't know how well the Scala compiler unfolds such function composition, but if it's worth the money of a functional language the actual code produced could be nicely optimized into zipping directly into a flat list.